# 12.04 Running Slow on Acer Aspire 5738ZG

Tags: 12.04, acer, aspire

I installed 12.04 but it seems to run rather slow (a little laggy when minimizing, some applications open slowly, YouTube 1080p videos are laggy as well).

I'm with the HD4650 graphics card and found some drivers that need to be activated but after I try to install them, I end up with an error saying that downloading and installing drivers failed.

Do you have any idea what's wrong, cos I think with this hardware, the OS must be running like a lightning.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [these tips](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/07/5-quick-tips-to-improve-ubuntu-1104.html) and also checked if there were processes that were [keeping my machine slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181894/ubuntu-12-04-running-slow-how-to-improve-performance).

Hope this will help!